# its impossible? combining {border-right,border-left: 1px solid black;}

Tags: html, css

I want the output to be like this:

```
|top|right|bottom|left|
```

So I tried `{border-right,border-left:1px solid black;}` but its not functioning.

So I tried `{border-right:1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black}` but the output is like this:

```
|top||right||bottom||left|
```

the question is it impossible to combine like this?: `{border-right,border-left:1px solid black;}`

Comment: You set border left for all items and on the last item set border right OR you set border right on all items and on the first item you set border left. You can target the first or last item with `:first-child` `last-child` assuming the items are the only children in the parent container

Comment: What is the issue here? This would be the correct format: `{border-right:1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;}`

Comment: @APAD1 OP is just having trouble achieving the desired result because he is getting double borders

Comment: on the html code my input is this:
<ul>
     <li class="top">top</li>
                      <li>right</li>
                  <li>bottom</li>
                       <li>left</li>
</ul>    


so, on the css, here's what i did.

ul li { border-right: 1px solid black; }
ul .top { border-left: 1px solid black; }
i put a class on the first list.

or maybe there's no need to put a class on the list, then on css i could just do this.

ul li:first-child { border-left: 1px solid black; }
ul li { border-right: 1px solid black; }.

thank you guys with all you comments and suggestions.. good day..

Answer (score 7):

You can do

```css
.yourclass {
  border-right:1px solid black;
  padding: 10px; /*just to make it readable */
}
.yourclass:first-child{
  border-left:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span class=yourclass>top</span>
<span class=yourclass>left</span>
<span class=yourclass>bottom</span>
<span class=yourclass>right</span>
```

In case the `.yourclass` elements aren't the only children of their parent, you may use `:first-of-type` instead (IE9+).

Comment: Note that this solution would require the .yourclass-elements to be the first elements in their container and might not be applicable in every situation :)

Comment: @NachoDawg just in case the HTML doesn't allow for first-child, I changed it to first-of-type.

Answer (score 1):

The css-selector you are looking for is

```
element+element
```

for example

```
.spanCoolBorder{
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.spanCoolBorder+.spanCoolBorder{
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

the element+element applies the css to the second element when it is placed directly after a case of the first element in the document flow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table{ border-collapse: collapse; }
td{ border-right: 1px solid black; }
td:first-child{ border-left: 1px solid black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Three ways you can achieve this here is the  DEMO

https://jsfiddle.net/rcshgqxe/

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
      div{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 50%;
        height: 200px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      .container1{
        border-right:  1px solid red;
        border-left:  1px solid red;

      }

      .container2{
        border: 1px solid red;
        border-top: 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
      }

      .container3{
        border-color: red;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
      }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container1">

    </div>

    <div class="container2">

    </div>

    <div class="container3">

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```